# Describe Dynamodb Table at Local Installation using endpoint URL?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, local, aws-cli

I have Installed DynamoDB Local Instance on my machine,

I want to Describe DynamoDB Tables which are created at this Local Instance of DynamoDB,

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

You Need to have installed [`awscli`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/describe-table.html) on your machine.

Steps to install `awscli` : [Click Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html)

After Installing, Run below command to Describe DynamoDb Table :

```
aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name tableName --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

**Note :** Here `--endpoint-url` is **Optional** & Used for *Local DynamoDB Installation* Only.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I run this on the local DynamoDB, `[Errno 22] Invalid argument` output is given. It looks like `--endpoint-url` option is not supported for `describe-table` operation :(. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/describe-table.html, there is no `--endpoint-url` option there.

Comment: Although yes, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Tools.CLI.html#Tools.CLI.UsingWithDDBLocal states that you can add `--endpoint-url` to _each_ command in `aws cli`, but this does not work :(